# what is the restriction function of f?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a function, and $f_{/A}:A\longrightarrow Y$ be a restriction function. 
I know, If G is an open subset of $Y$, then $f_{/A}^{-1}(G)=f^{-1}(G)\cap A$.
But, I'm not sure about if $G$ is an open subset of $X$, then $f_{/A}(G)=f(G)\cap A$ ?

Comment: Note that $A$ is a subset of $X,$ while $f(G)$ is a subset of $Y.$ So, in general, it doesn't make sense to talk about $f(G) \cap A$. Did you mean to write $f(G) \cap f(A)?$

Comment: well, i mean what is $f_{/A}(G)$ equal to? in general

Comment: Note that $f_{|A}(G)$ is meaningful only when $G\subseteq A$ to begin with. And thus $f_{|A}(G)=f(G)$. There's nothing more to that.